# VBA insert number of rows depending on variable at end of table

Tags: excel, vba, rows

I'm trying to write some code to even out the number of rows in two different tables, table 1 (MaintSetup) is the table where the user would fill out all the information while table 2 (MaintSched) displays it. Users should really only ever need to add rows to table 1, so I was looking to create some code that would automatically add rows to table 2 based on the difference between the rows.

I'm not super competent with VBA so I used some excel functions to calculate the difference in rows and have it listed in cell K9 (IE: if table 1 is 3 rows longer then table 2 cell K9 on the worksheet background has "3" in it.

I came up with some code for adding a specified number of rows but couldn't adapt it for a varying number of rows. This is what I had come up with, originally i was just 1 to 10 for adding 10 lines.

```
Sheets("Background").Select
Dim Dif As Integer
Diff = Range("K9")

Sheets("Maintenance Setup").Select

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("MaintSched")

Dim i As Byte
    For i = 1 To Diff
    tbl.ListRows.Add
Next i
```

Comment: What are you trying to do at the point you have `Diff = Range("K9")
Range("K11") = Diff` ?

Comment: Do both of your tables start at the same row? (i.e. are your table headers at same row number?)

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? This sounds like you could use PowerQuery to make 1 table a source, and another table, the 'Query'. Then just choose how you want PowerQuery to refresh the tables (at interval, manual, on event).

Comment: The Range("K11") = Diff was something i was using just to make sure part of my code was working and I no longer need it, forgot to delete it before posting the code here. The cell that actually contains the difference in number of rows is actually "K9" so i was setting my variable as Diff = K9 that was Diff would be 3 if there were rows difference between table 1 and 2.

Comment: Both tables start on the same row

Comment: Excel 2019, I haven't hear of PowerQuery, I feel like changing things now would cause more issues then it's worth as I have a bunch of formatting and macros as it is for the second table but I will definitely keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just messed up my variable and called defined it as Dif while trying to use Diff. The below code worked for me with the minor edit. Also found out Dim i as byte was not required.

```
Sheets("Background").Select
Dim **Diff** As Integer
Diff = Range("K9")

Sheets("Maintenance Setup").Select

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("MaintSched")

Dim i As Byte
    For i = 1 To Diff
    tbl.ListRows.Add
Next i
```

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module and you wouldn't have this issue.